# Privately owned land in Japan

Tags: geospatial, japan

I need to find out if a piece of land is privately owned or not. I probably can go to a public office and find that out. But I'm doing this on a random basis. So it's too complicated.

Is there a map/data/service where I can see if a land is privately owned?

There's https://www.gsi.go.jp/ENGLISH/index.html
But at least I haven't figured out how to display this data.